Is there any surprising coincidence that God solves?
In the case of fine tuning, does God really explain the improbability of the right constants being chosen for life? I’m failing to see how “God wanted the constants to be so” tells us why a particular set of constants were chosen instead of another. This is because we would still have no explanation for why a God who wants this exists in the first place. Thus, by extension, the “surprise” of the coincidence remains, while all the disadvantages of God (such as being a theory without independent evidence) remains.
Is there any other coincidence that God does explain? For example, what about the people who report seeing things at the top of closets on their death bed during near death experiences? Could God explain these?
Or dreams where someone sees God and an event happens in the dream and then the next day, that same event happens? Would God explain something like this that would otherwise be a surprising coincidence?

I’d say it’s similar to the second question but not exactly but it is closed and it has no answers (and comments point out how the close doesn’t make sense).

@DikranMarsupial Are any philosophical questions answerable by facts? That's new to me. If not, then is this just a site to ask questions about the history of philosophy? If people ask questions of interpretation - is any interpretation really uncontroversial? - I believe questions should only be closed if there is obvious trolling going on or if a question is obviously off-topic (for instance purely political or technical). Even so, there may be borderline cases.

@DikranMarsupial - Ah, I wasn't aware of the history in this case. Agree with your points too.

No one claims that God arbitrarily wanted the constants to have certain values. This is a straw man argument.

The question is ill posed. "X is not known to exist" and "the reason for X is unknown" and even "X did not cause Y" have no bearing whatsoever on the truth or falsehood of "Y if X".

@DavidGudeman The question doesn’t say that God arbitrarily wanted the constants to have certain values either. Your comment is the straw man. Point me to where that was said. Hint: you won’t find it

@DikranMarsupial did you mean to say “they are” instead of “the are”?

"God" is a conceptional joker who solves every problem as far as the problem does not contradict logic - thanks to his omnipotence.
History shows that some theologians even discussed solutions to problems which contradict common logic.

This is supposed to be a philosophy site, not a snarky new atheist site.

@Dikran Marsupial Sorry, I did not read your whole comment before. But I will like your last comment.

@DikranMarsupial I corrected the typo now.

@DikranMarsupial Prior beliefs should be justified. If they are ridiculous such as the belief in Santa Claus, they should be attacked, not given leeway. How do you argue against someone who has a prior belief in Santa Claus? Let me know please

@DikranMarsupial how humble someone is shouldn’t matter with respect to the truth. I was honestly just curious as to how people view god as an explanation for things

@DikranMarsupial You are establishing a standard you yourself don’t follow. Do you respect flat earth believers, Santa Claus believers, people who believe they are being watched by 100 aliens every day, people who think a demon in their room is their best friend, etc? I guarantee that even if you don’t, you atleast privately think it is ridiculous. Simply speaking what you believe in doesn’t make you arrogant, and god isn’t a special belief where one must hold back their confidence for
